# Regular Expression: not containing and look-ahead

Tags: regex

With this expression: `.*(?=good)` i can get:

```
text is good -> text is
```

But how to supplement this expression so that it also work in the following case:

```
text is not good -> NOT MATCH or empty string
```

Comment: Try `^(?!.* not good\b).*(?= good\b)` https://regex101.com/r/4HVqRc/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative Lookbehind:

```
.+(?<!not )(?=good)
```

This ensures that the position where the Lookahead starts is *not* preceded by `"not "`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lvgdML/1)**.

If you want to make sure that the word "not" doesn't appear anywhere before the Lookahead, you may use:

```
^(?:(?!not).)+(?=good)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JEwwua/2)**.

And if you want to make sure that the word "not" doesn't appear anywhere in the string (even after the Lookahead), you may use:

```
^(?!.*not).+(?=good)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fHE5O6/1)**.

P.S. Use `\bnot\b` if the rejected "not" must be a whole word (e.g., if you want to allow "knot").

Comment: @Wiktor Is `(?!not).` better than `(?<!not).` in terms of performance or something else?

Comment: @Wiktor Can you please elaborate? Or refer me to a relevant article/post? I tried looking it up but didn't find anything that explains the difference. There's probably something I'm not seeing but as far as I can tell, the lookbehind does the same job.

Comment: See [Tempered Greedy Token - What is different about placing the dot before the negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks, I did find this post but didn't understand why a Lookbehind wouldn't work the same at first. I think I figured it out now. `(?<!not).+` will match "notgood" because the dot must match what's _after_ the Lookbehind, unlike with the Lookahead where the dot would match the first character. Thanks again!

Comment: *Tempered* dot pattern means the *dot* is tempered, "restricted". The lookbehind does not temper the dot, it just fails its match if some pattern is not present immediately to the left of it. You may use  `(?:(?!some pattern).)*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assert from the start of the string that it does not contain `not good`

Then use a non greedy quantifier to match until the first occurrence of `good` to the right (In case good occurs more than once)

```
^(?!.*\bnot good\b).*?(?= good\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `.*\bnot good\b` Match `not good` between word boundaries
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.*?` Match any char as least as possible *(In case of more occurrences of `good`, stop before the first)*
- `(?= good\b)` Positive lookahead, assert  `good` at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O7AU0u/1)